# How do I tell BitmapFactory.decodeStream to give me a full quality image?

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-image

So I have the following code in an `AsyncTask`. The `AsyncTask` takes in a url to an image file, downloads it into a Bitmap, saves the Bitmap off to disk somewhere, and then displays the Bitmap in an existing `ImageView`.

Here's the implementation of the `doInBackground()` call for my AsyncTask:

```
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try {
            URL image_url = new URL(urls[0]);
            String image_url_prefix_regex = "http://www\\.somewebsite\\.com";
            if (externalStorageIsAvailable()) {
                String file_path = getExternalFilesDir(null).getPath() + image_url.toString().replaceAll(image_url_prefix_regex, "");
                File target_file = new File(file_path);
                if (!target_file.getParentFile().exists()) {
                    target_file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
                }

                BitmapFactory.Options bitmap_options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                bitmap_options.inScaled = false;
                bitmap_options.inDither = false;
                bitmap_options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
                bitmap_options.inPreferQualityOverSpeed = true;
                bitmap_options.inSampleSize = 1;

                Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(image_url.openStream(), null, bitmap_options);
                image.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, new FileOutputStream(target_file));
                return image;
            }
        }
        catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Log.v(DEBUG_TAG, "Error: Caught MalformedURLException");
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            Log.v(DEBUG_TAG, "Error: Caught IOException");
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Then later in the `onPostExecute()` call I have this:

```
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap image) {
        ImageView mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.main_image);
        mImageView.setImageBitmap(image);
    }
```

Yet when the code downloads and displays the image, the image is reduced in size and quality. How do I make it so that the resulting image is full quality? Those `BitmapFactory`.Options settings are the things I've tried thus far, but they did not seem to work.

Note that I'm not asking about the image that gets saved to external storage. I think that one will likely be of lower quality due to getting compressed again, but that shouldn't affect the image I'm sending to my `ImageView`, which is what I'm asking about. Of course, if there's anything wrong with these assumptions please point them out.

Answer (score -1):

Why you are using Bitmap factory options while decoding bitmap Stream ? 
Just use the

```
 Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(image_url.openStream());
```

instead of

```
Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(image_url.openStream(), null, bitmap_options);
```